# Beginner Python: Extract List to integer

Tags: python, list, formatting, extract

I am a beginner programmer and I need help with extracting the numbers from a list and converting them back to integers. The program takes a numerical input (like 305.67) and splits to 305 and 67. Attached is the code that shows the unfinished portion. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

```
def getDollarFormatText(dolAndCent):

    separateDolCent = str(dolAndCent).rsplit('.',1)

    return separateDolCent
```

Comment: if you are trying to get fractional and rational parts of a float, use `modf`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are so close!

```
def getDollarFormatText(dolAndCent):

    separateDolCent = [int(x) for x in str(dolAndCent).split('.')]

    return separateDolCent
```

What I have done in [int(x) for x in dolAndCent.split('.')] is made a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) (list comprehensions are a *very* common idiom in python and very powerful once you get familiar with them).  Essentially, it splits your string on the '.' (as you did before), then creates a little loop to loop over each element (the part before and after the '.').  For each of these, it converts to an integer with the `int`. function.

I changed `rsplit` to `split` because it doesn't matter which side of the string you split from, and I removed the `1` because there is only one '.' anyway.

---

As a side note, there is no reason to create the `separateDolCent` variable:

```
def get_dollar_format_text(dol_and_cent):
    '''Returns the dollar and cents part of a money amount as
    a two element list of integers, where the first element is
    dollars and the second is cents.
    '''
    return [int(x) for x in str(dol_and_cent).split('.')]
```

Notice how I changed your variables from `camelCase` to `using_underscores`.  This is a preferred in the python community for function and variable names.  I also added some documentation to your function using a docstring.

---

If you need to handle numbers like `2`, `3.4` or `345.4311`, you can make the following edit to your code:

```
def get_dollar_format_text(dol_and_cent):
    '''Returns the dollar and cents part of a money amount as
    a two element list of integers, where the first element is
    dollars and the second is cents.
    '''
    return [int(x) for x in '{0:.2f}'.format(dol_and_cent).split('.')]
```

What this does is force the number to be formatted with two decimal places always, so that `2` becomes `2.00`, `3.4` becomes `3.40`, and `345.4311` becomes `345.43`.  This way, you *always* get cents with two decimals.

Comment: @Jr. I edited my answer a bit to handle cases of integer dollar amounts, or fractional cents.

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there:

```
def getDollarFormatText(dolAndCent):

    separateDolCent = map(int,str(dolAndCent).rsplit('.',1))

    return separateDolCent
```

> How to be able to save each integer into a new variable?

Just extract them into two vars (eg. `a` and `b`):

```
def getDollarFormatText(dolAndCent):

        a,b = map(int,str(dolAndCent).rsplit('.',1))

        print a
        print b

getDollarFormatText("5.70")
```

This will print:

```
5
70
```

Comment: Awesome, by any chance would you also know how to be able to save each integer into a new variable?